# How to prevent/stop/disable android SDK EditText exposed to application class

Tags: android, security, android-edittext, android-security, android-textinputedittext

I have an SDK that contains MYSDKActivity. In this activity layout, I have 1 edit text where the user can enter his card number. Any android Client who is integrating this SDK, can use **ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** in their application class and register **text watcher** on this edit text and can listen to user card number input.

I want to prevent SDK's edit text usage via the Application class. Only my SDK can access this edit text and perform some action. I want to block usage outside my SDK.

```
public class MyDemoApp extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof MYSDKActivity) {
        final TextInputLayout textInputLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.my_sdk_edit_text);
        if (textInputLayout != null) {
            ViewGroup textInputLayoutViewGroup = ((ViewGroup) textInputLayout.getChildAt(0));
            for (int i = 0; i < textInputLayoutViewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = textInputLayoutViewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof TextInputEditText) {
                    Log.v("USER Input",  ((TextInputEditText) child).getText().toString());
                    ((TextInputEditText) child).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            Log.v("USER Input", s.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider not using Android framework widget, use a SurfaceView and render your own keypad / edit field for secure data entry. Assuming you are following [Tapjacking recommendations](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/tapjacking) there still isn't anything preventing reverse engineering your SDK code and having a malicious actor send fraudulent data to your server side, but anyone using your SDK should be registered so why would an SDK integrator be doing bad-actor things?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve this

1. Create a custom layout which doesn't exposes methods like gettext and addTextWatcher.
2. Never store this data as plain string if you are storing this on the store.(Use encryption).

Comment: First won't actually work as the malicious client could always access private fields via reflection.
Second one is interesting though, but you will have a small amount of time between user entering his data and encryption so it can be accessed at that moment. Still, it narrows the window of opportunity for a malicious actor.

Comment: IMHO You can disable reflection for the custom view using the SecurityManager in your custom view constructor class for more detail.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218973/java-security-manager-completely-disable-reflection

Comment: On Android it is not true https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityManager - "Security managers do not provide a secure environment for executing untrusted code and are unsupported on Android. Untrusted code cannot be safely isolated within a single VM on Android. Application developers can assume that there's no SecurityManager installed, i.e. System.getSecurityManager() will return null."